# Install NDAS on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint

I'm trying to get Iocell NetDisk to work with Linux Mint 15.
The [Iocell-Website](http://www.iocellnetworks.com/support-main/#Drivers) directed me [here](https://github.com/iocellnetworks/ndas4linux/wiki/How-to-build,-install-and-remove-.deb-ndas-packages).
I followed the steps given, up until

```
sudo module-asisstant auto-install ndas
```

This one says: "Bad Luck, no fitting headers to the kernel were found."

"You can install the headers in package linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic. For most modules this is enough, without having the full kernel source."

However, linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic are already installed.

Any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: I assume you are using linux kernel 3.8.0-19-generic? What does `uname -a` say?

Comment: XXX@XXX-EasyNote-TSX62HR ~ $ uname -a               
Linux XXX-EasyNote-TSX62HR 3.8.0-19-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:16:28 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

> For most modules this is enough, without having the full kernel source.

Apparently, not for this one. Try installing all headers, and source packages, not just the `generic` package:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source linux-headers-3.8.0-19-all
```